# SQL Server SORT Dynamic Pivot Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, pivot

I have an dynamic SQL query which is returning the result as desired but the only problem is the resultant pivot columns are not getting selected in correct order.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns_pivot NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns_pivot = COALESCE(@columns_pivot + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Week_No)
  ,@columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ', '') + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Week_No) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Week_No) + ''
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT DATEPART(wk,T_Date) As Week_No
   FROM [VISIT].[dbo].[Report]
   WHERE DATEPART(m,T_Date) = 5
   ORDER BY Week_No DESC) x; // This query returns Column 'Week_No' in order 22,21,20,19,18 (As Desired)
Edit: //But when Order By Clause is removed it returns 21,18,19,22,20 which is the actual output( Not Desired)

SET @sql = '
SELECT ABC, ' + @columns + '
FROM

 (Select TOP 100 PERCENT
 ABC
,SUM(CASE WHEN Type = A THEN Sum ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue
,DATEPART(wk,T_Date) As Week_No
 FROM [VISIT].[dbo].[Report]
 GROUP BY ABC
,DATEPART(wk,T_Date)
 ORDER BY Week_No DESC) As j 
 PIVOT(
 max(Revenue)
 FOR Week_No in (' + @columns_pivot + ')) As p '
```

Final result returns columns in the order ABC, 21, 18, 19, 22, 20

But I want the result As ABC, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18.

I saw few posts but was not able to figure out what is wrong with my query. Can someone please point what I have to change in the Query to get the desired output. Where exactly do I have to put the ORDER BY clause

In short when the  **Select Distinct** statement returns the column **Week_No** in Desc Order why the variables **@columns** and **@columns_pivot** don't get it in Desc order

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error if you keep the order by in the desired position?

Comment: I dont get any error but what I dont understand is when the first select statement returns week number in descending order why the variables @ columns & @ columns_pivot don't get it in descending order

Comment: It is becuase the column names you specify in the IN part of the Pivot query, determines the position of the column. It is similar to normal select query. If you say select a,b from table, then a displayed first and b displayed second. Where as if you say select b,a from table then b is displayed first and a displayed second

Comment: Ya I got it dats what i need to change the order.. I want the week_no to appear in Descending order in the variable @columns_pivot and @ columns

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by storing Week_No in a temp table and apply clustered indexing to it.
Here is the code I added:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp


SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) = :month
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT DATEPART(wk,Tour_Datum) As Week_No into #temp
FROM [VISITOUR].[dbo].[BI_001_ADM_Report]
WHERE DATEPART(m,Tour_Datum) = @params

--Clustered index is created on week_no in acending order, so that data is physically stored in that way
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cix_wekno ON #temp(Week_No ASC)
```